# How do it make a .air, I have tried the adl and adt but it doesn't work for me

Tags: air, adobe

I downloaded the last AIR SKD, I'm using Windows Vista.
I have trying to make a helloworld in Adobe air and it's not working//

what should I do?

Comment: This is a pretty poor question. You should at least show the code you tried that didn't work. Then we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) for AIR development, it has debugging, packaging, badge creation etc. etc. and best of all , it's free.

Comment: Absolutely true. Tested and verified ;) Don't forget that you should install its Adobe AIR plug-in though.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the relevant documentation.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd6.html)

Use the **adt**.

Comment: Thanks Joel, as I said, I have tried using the adt, but it doesn't work for me.. when I drop my example, it doesn't do nothing